# What is this algorithm called and is it any good?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

The other day, I came up with an idea for a sorting algorithm :

```
public int[] sort(int array[]){
    int biggest = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        if(array[i]>biggest){biggest = array[i];} // getting biggest value in array
    }
    boolean[] array2 = new boolean[biggest]; // creating an array of size biggest

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array2[array[i]] = true; // putting item at item's value index in array2
    }
    
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
        if(array2[i]){
            array[index] = i; //putting all items ordered in array
            index ++;
        }
    }
    
    return array;
}
```

Basically, I'm creating an array of size [biggest in the sorting array] and I put each item in it at index [value of item]. Then, I go through the array and put each element, ordered in a new array, sorted.

first, surelly I'm not the first one to think about this, am I?
second, for me it looks like th most efficient sorting algorithm in the world, so why am I not seeing it anywhere? What's it's problem?

Comment: When you fix the problem that it requires all elements to be distinct (doesn't work for [1,2,2,3], for example), then this is called "counting sort".  It is not efficient for inputs like [1,5632352233,2]

Comment: Why is it  not efficient?

Comment: Because the third loop counts to 5632352233.

Comment: It's also not space efficient. The code would allocate an enormous `array2`  with Tim's example, just to sort 3 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As people have been saying in the comments, this algorithm is called counting sort. It seems to be very efficient if you have a list of non-repeating numbers of which its highest number isn't too much bigger than its length. It has three major issues though:

1. If a number is repeated in the list to sort, the number has no where to go, it can't be handled by the system.
2. If you have a number that is much larger than the list's length, it's going to create and ggo through a huge list for a small amount of numbers, making it inefficient.
3. It's not memory-efficient. The worst case is in the example made by @Matt Timmermans , were you would need a 5 632 352 233 long array just to sort 3 items.

Answer (score -1):

I can say that your algorithm's time complexity is O(n^3).
It has 3 for loops that iterates whole array.
Well known algorithms like mergesort has time complexity of O(n log n).
Quicksort, another well known algorithm, has time complexity of O(n log n), on average, O(n^2) in worst cases.
You might think that your logic is pretty efficient.
But in real world, there are bunch of datas which doesn't fit your logic.
That means your algorithm can go through whole iterations. Resulting time complexity of O(n^3).
Hope my answer helped!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You state an *upper bound* which is valid as such. However, only two of the loops mentioned iterate `array`, and none is a *nested* loop. The third loop iterates `array2`. Can you give a *tight* (er) upper bound on run-time as *n* keeps increasing? How about including *biggest*?

Comment: I think you made a mistake here, The big O notation wouldn't be O(n^3), it would be O(3n) (if biggest = array.length), because it loops three times though the array. It doesn't check each item for each item for each item. But thanks for your intervention :)

Comment: @greybeard I"m not sure what you are trying to say... Are you asking if I could limit the size of _biggest_? I guess some optimisation could be done...

Comment: (@Gyoo: While there's a constant factor to be dropped from *3n*, O(n) is a proper subset of O(n³), any function in O(n) is in O(n³), too: the latter *is* a valid upper bound. Calling the biggest value *b* and the *range* (b - smallest) *r*, going from O(n+b) to O(n+r) may or may not lead to sparking an idea for a variation that has been thought up, published, named & analysed.)